# Книги по защите информации

Tags: книги, защита, информатика

Добрый вечер!
Посоветуйте книги по защите информации и кибер атак , и литературу по сопутствующим темам.

Буду признателен за название авторов и название книги.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю, защита это или наоборот, но мне нравятся книжки и статьи Криса Касперски.

Многое, конечно не припомню, но под рукой оказались:

"Записки исследователя компьютерных вирусов" 2006 г.

и "Техника сетевых атак" 2001 г.

А также Дмитрий Скляров (это он взломал adobe e-books) "Искусство защиты и взлома информации" 2004 г.

и Андрей Чмора "Современная прикладная криптография" 2001 г.

Я уже давно "плотно" не интересовался данной темой. Думаю, что за эти лет пять, появились интересные книжки. Также, надо упомянуть журнал "Хакер". Думаю в его архиве можно найти много "наводок".

Answer (score 3):

Ну по сопутствующим вот еще книжки:

Джеймс С. Фостер "Защита от взлома. Сокеты, shell-код, эксплойты"

Г. Хоглунд, Дж. Батлер "Руткиты, внедрение в ядро Windows"

Кэрриэ Б. "Криминалистический анализ файловых систем"

Дж. Макнамара "Секреты компьютерного шпионажа: тактика и контрмеры"

Джон Эриксон "Хакинг. Искусство эксплойта"

Вообще эта тема защиты информации настолько интересна и многогранна, что одними книжками не обойтись: интернет, копание в исходниках, чтение, изучение, исследование и так далее - увлекательный процесс ))

Comment: + Талант и умение думать не стандартно, вроде так все объясняли )

Answer (score 1):

Если вдруг одной теории будет недостаточно, посмотри в сторону онлайн соревнований и квестов CTF.
В этой статье есть немного вводной информации о том, что это [CTF в России](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64216/).

Comment: Хорошо гляну.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно здесь вы найдете что-то подходящее по вашему вопросу: http://isu-sibadi.ru/scince/books/index.php